# How to send a txt data as text in a channel discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I try to send the text of a txt data as message. I dont find any to do it with Discord.py 1.6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work

```
with open("FILE_PATH", "r") as file:
    message_text = file.read()

channel.send(message_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be just the same as uploading an image.

Use:

```
channel.send(file=discord.File('filename.txt'))
```

Read more:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-upload-an-image

Comment: if i use it i get it not as text i get it as txt data

Comment: I see what you mean. I thought you meant like how you send a text message that's over 2000 characters, not how to convert a txt file to a string. Good luck!